# TypeError: Cannot read property 'Constants' of undefined

Tags: javascript, react-native

I am trying to create a Flatlist with youtube videos from my youtube channel but every time i click on the video to play it I get this error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'Constants' of undefined

```
const YOUTUBE_VIDEOS = [
  { id: 'dQw4w9WgXcQ', title: 'Video 1' },
  { id: '3tmd-ClpJxA', title: 'Video 2' },
  // ... more video IDs
];

const DrillScreen = () => {
  const [selectedVideo, setSelectedVideo] = useState(null);

  const handleVideoPress = (videoId) => {
    setSelectedVideo(videoId);
  };

  const closeModal = () => {
    setSelectedVideo(null);
  };

  const renderItem = ({ item }) => (
    <TouchableOpacity style={styles.videoContainer} onPress={() => handleVideoPress(item.id)}>
      <Image
        style={styles.thumbnail}
        source={{ uri: `https://img.youtube.com/vi/${item.id}/0.jpg` }}
      />
      <Text style={styles.videoTitle}>{item.title}</Text>
    </TouchableOpacity>
  );

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <FlatList
        data={YOUTUBE_VIDEOS}
        renderItem={renderItem}
        keyExtractor={(item) => item.id}
      />
      {selectedVideo && (
        <Modal
          animationType="slide"
          transparent={false}
          visible={true}
          onRequestClose={closeModal}
        >
          <View style={styles.modalContainer}>
            <Video
              source={{ uri: `https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=${selectedVideo}` }} // This might not work directly due to YouTube restrictions.
              style={styles.fullScreen}
              controls={true}
              onError={(error) => {
                console.log('Video Error', error);
                closeModal();
              }}
            />
            <TouchableOpacity style={styles.closeButton} onPress={closeModal}>
              <Text style={styles.closeText}>Close</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
          </View>
        </Modal>
      )}
    </View>
  );
};


export default DrillScreen;
```

Anyone knows why i am having this issue? Thank you for the help

Comment: Where are you using `Constants`? I don't see it anywhere in the code you shared.

Comment: Are you using Expo  or Expo related package?

Comment: Ye, I am using Expo package